# Selecciona columna con un valor especifico SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una tabla similar al ejemplo de la imagen. En mi backend recibo dos dígitos por ejemplo si yo recibo los números 03 solo me interesaría la tercera columna específicamente el dato 03YEPT.

¿Existe alguna manera de solo traer la columna que a mi me interesa desde la consulta en la base de datos?

Sin la necesidad de traer las cuatro columnas a mi backend y tener que iterarlas para tomar la que me interesa

Quiero traer solo la columna que me interesa desde la consulta a la base de datos si es posible

Comment: `Select DATO3  from TUTABLA where DATO3 like'03%'`, puedes poder una variable  para remplazar el 03 , pero si tienes mas datos , deberas filtrar por id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con un `SELECT CASE`, consultando los 4 campos y devolviendo el valor que se ajusta a tu consulta.

```
select case 
    when dato1 like '03%' then dato1 
    when dato2 like '03%' then Dato2 
    when dato3 like '03%' then Dato3 
    when dato4 like '03%' then Dato4 
    end as Resultado
from #tmp
```

Por ejemplo

```
create table #tmp(dato1 varchar(10), dato2 varchar(10),dato3 varchar(10),dato4 varchar(10))

insert into #tmp values ('0100', '0200', '0300', '0400')
insert into #tmp values ('0100', '0300', '0500', '0400')

select case when dato1 like '03%' then dato1 
when dato2 like '03%' then Dato2 
when dato3 like '03%' then Dato3 
when dato4 like '03%' then Dato4 end as Resultado
from #tmp
```

Esto devolvería

```
Resultado
0300
0300
```

Tendrías el resultado esperado, pero no sabrías de que columna viene cada uno de los registros encontrados.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando case sobre el parámetro recibido puedes retornar la columna para cada row

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DATOS (DATO1 VARCHAR(10), DATO2 VARCHAR(10), DATO3 VARCHAR(10), DATO4 VARCHAR(10))
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.DATOS
VALUES
('01ABDM','02ASDM','03YEPT','04YETDF');
GO
DECLARE @PARAM VARCHAR(2)='03'

SELECT CASE CAST(@PARAM AS INT) 
        WHEN 1 THEN DATO1
        WHEN 2 THEN DATO2
        WHEN 3 THEN DATO3
        WHEN 4 THEN DATO4
        ELSE 'Parametro incorrecto' END AS DATOS
    FROM dbo.DATOS;
```

O choose si dispones de Sql Server 2012 o superior

```
DECLARE @PARAM VARCHAR(2)='03'

SELECT CHOOSE(CAST(@PARAM AS INT),DATO1,DATO2,DATO3,DATO4) AS DATOS
FROM dbo.datos
```

[Case vs choose vs iif](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/30/case-vs-choose-vs-iif/)

[image: solución]